# Fastest way to select a value from a single row table

Tags: dax

I have a disconnected table called *TableX* with two columns and a single row of data:

```
Date  | Amount
4-Jan | 10.5
```

There will always only be 1 row of data.
The model it is part of is huge and the amount 10.5 will be used extensively in measures.

To extract 10.5 from this table I've used the following:

```
AmountValue := MIN(TableX[Amount])
```

Is `MIN` the fastest way to extract this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here test from DaxStudio (5 Cold + 5 Hot cache execution) for disconnected table containin only one row as in your example :

```
DEFINE
MEASURE 'TableX'[AmountValue3] = ALL(TableX[Amount])

evaluate
{[AmountValue2]}
```

[image]

```
DEFINE
MEASURE 'TableX'[AmountValue2] = Values(TableX[Amount])

evaluate
{[AmountValue2]}
```

[image]

```
DEFINE 
MEASURE 'TableX'[AmountValue] = min(TableX[Amount])

evaluate
{[AmountValue]}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - this is pretty conclusive of the alternatives presented it is very fast using min